# How do I specify UseDevelopmentStorage=true for azure 2.5 sdk web role diagnostics

Tags: azure, emulation, diagnostics

To run in the emulator you would normally set the connection string for the diagnostics to:

**UseDevelopmentStorage=true**

However if you use azure 2.5 sdk, there is no longer a field for connection string. Instead there is a storage account credentials configuration tool. If you look in the diagnostics.wadcfgx file there is a section for the configuration

```
<PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
   <StorageAccount name="diagnosticlogging" key="Yjzl/0m3zyF0F6VNThdzflY408tSpsqe/6ofjFQ4gVhDylyBHvZRhXg41reSLGknWX4wXjq575bcgf++L+8DZg==" endpoint="" />
</PrivateConfig>
```

This just reflects what is in the configuration tool.

I have found the answer as I write this, so I'll share:

You can't do it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx
Check out the breaking changes section:
**Diagnostics logs are not collected in the Azure compute emulator**

Great.

UPDATE:
See Justin's comment below

Comment: Would you mind putting that as an answer (and accept it)?

Comment: FYI - In 2.6, they changed it back and the local emulator is supposed to support diagnostics using connection string UseDevelopmentStorage=true.  "The diagnostics storage account connection string (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString) is stored once again in the service configuration (.cscfg) file. In Azure SDK 2.5 the diagnostics storage account was specified in the diagnostics.wadcfgx file."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to Guarav I shall add this as the answer and accept it:

I have found the answer as I write this, so I'll share:

You can't do it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx Check out the breaking changes section: Diagnostics logs are not collected in the Azure compute emulator

Great.

UPDATE: See Justin's comment on the original post (above)

Answer (score 0):

Then how come we can configure diagnostic with azure storage account to synch.

Please share steps to configure diagnostic in webrole with sdk 2.5 as i tried and not updated the logs in azure storage account.

Thanks,